# Keeping an SdtBlock on the same page

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I am doing some open xml manipulations on word document.

It has several sdt content, all contained in a sdt block.

I copy paste programatically the sdt block each time I need.

The thing is, I don't success keeping the sdt block on a single page.

I tried to add a style in word directly to the sdt block but this doesn't work.

The conditions are :

one sdt block must be entirely on the same page.

After searching a lot, I did'nt find any solutions that fit my need. Only solutions concerning one paragraph, and not a sdt block containing sdt contents, that is way different.

If it is possible : Does it must be in word? In the c# code?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the suggestions made by James, you can also control how Word lays out a page by setting paragraph formatting options. The relevant ones in your case are KeepWithNext (keeps contiguous paragraphsj together on the same page) and KeepTogether (keeps the content of a single paragraph on the same page).

Note that if the content is too long for a single page, then the options will have no effect at all. So it's important to make sure the last paragraph of a "block" is NOT formatted KeepWithNext.

In the Open XML SDK this is the KeepNext class, which corresponds to w:keepNext
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.keepnext(v=office.14).aspx

And the KeepLines class (w:keepLines): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.keeplines(v=office.14).aspx

Both are children of the paragraph Properties (w:pPr) element.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing much in ooxml to define pages, it's a flowing document and word paginates it when it opens as it thinks is best, Assuming your block fits on a single page (page size, margins, etc). The only way you'd guarantee it gets its own page is to

1. Put a page break before it (This will result in blank pages unless you have some way of checking if the previous page will fit the intended block)
2. Put it in a textbox (Not sure if an sdt block can go in a text box)
3. Put it in a table cell (1x1 table with invisible border) and set the table properties not to break a row across pages.